# Datetime arithmetic in Spring JPA query annotation

Tags: java, spring, datetime, jpa

I have a table with a `created` column which is of type `DATETIME` and is set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on creation.

I also have a Spring JPA repository to handle said table, and would like to create an annotated query to find rows which exist for more than `timeout` time, in the following style:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE (e.created < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - timeout")
List<Entity> findOldEntries(@Param("timeout") int timeout);
```

What is the correct syntax for this query, and which units of "timeout" does it expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK JPA doesn't support time periods. Alternatively, you can use [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html):

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE (e.created < ?#{@yourRepo.secondsBefore(#timeout))}")
List<Entity> findOldEntries(@Param("timeout") int timeout);

// add a method that returns an Instant that matches your time
default Instant secondsBefore(int seconds) {
    return Instant.now().minus(seconds, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Questions: (1) how does SpEL bind @yourRepo with the repository? Does `@yourRepo`  variable always point to current repository? (2) What actually happens: (2A) is the query submitted with the constraint or (2B) The result set is filtered?